# How to append 2 divs in every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, settimeout, intervals

I tried to use `setInterval` to show the span every 10 seconds but seems it's not taking effect. Currently, the span continuously display even without 10 seconds. How to fix it?

```js
var i = 0;
var messages = {from: {type: "Other"}};
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === 2) return clearInterval(myInterval);
  if (messages.from.type === "Other") {
    $('.chat_converse').append("<span class='msg_item'>lorem ipsum</p></span>");
  }

  $('.chat_converse').append("<span class='msg_item2'>textextext</p></span>");
  i++;
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat_converse"></div>
```

What I need to expect is to display 2 span in every 10 seconds and display additional append after each 2 span.

Expected output:

```
<div class="chat_converse">
  <span class="msg_item">lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="msg_item">lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="msg_item2">textextext

  </span><span class="msg_item">lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="msg_item">lorem ipsum</span>
  <span class="msg_item2">textextext</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Please could you clear your problem statement a bit. Thanks

Comment: @PranavCBalan sorry typo error, it's now updated

Comment: where your code is running ?

Comment: @amrendersingh, the expected output is to display a 2 span for each interval and after each 2 span there's a new append html

Comment: @OleDevL : can you reproduce the issue in stacksnippet or https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @OleDevL, So you want, if more than one message sent between 10 seconds, those messaged should be merged under one div, means look like, one message !!!. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I've converted your code to a stack snippet, it seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. can you help me to fix it? I need to display 2 `span.msg_item` for each interval then for each 2 span it will display the span with `msg_item2`

Comment: @PranavCBalan, im trying to display 2 `span.msg_item` for each interval then for each 2 span it will display the span with msg_item2

Comment: @OleDevL I don't understand what you're trying to say there. Can you show what you want the HTML to look like after a couple of iterations?

Comment: @OleDevL : can you reproduce the issue? you code works as expected

Comment: @PranavCBalan the current output in the post, is only display 1 span from `msg_item` and 1 span from `msg_item2`. Im trying to do is display 2 span from `msg_item` then 1 span from `msg_item` one at a time

Comment: from where `messages` is updating ???

Comment: @Barmar please see the updated post with expected output

Comment: @PranavCBalan please see the updated post

Comment: It's updating content after 10 seconds... I couldn't able to see any issue here

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes but my expected output is different from the current. please see the expected out in my post :)